# Can I ask a specific technical question about a small appliance?

Tags: discussion

I have a technical question about a small appliance that doesn't fit with the Home Improvement stack exchange. But it's not an electrical engineering question but a electrical safety question and is fairly specific (burnt probe end on skillet controller probe, is it normal?) Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for asking, but no, it doesn't fit here either. It would fall either into the "usage" or "repair" categories, which are both off-topic.

You can try our chat area to see whether anyone there is interested in discussing it.